# How to call another post mapping api in another api in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I made a postmapping call - (/login) I just want to call (/sendotp) api in it. I am making a project where if a person successfully login he will get a otp.
This is my code in controller class in springboot -

Controller classs ---

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public SessionHandling loginUser(@RequestBody SessionHandling login) throws Exception {
        String tempEmailId = login.getEmail();
        String takePassword = login.getPassword();
        SessionHandling UserObj = null;
        if(tempEmailId != null && takePassword != null) {
        UserObj = service.fetchUserByEmailIdAndPassword(tempEmailId, takePassword); 
        }
        if(UserObj == null) {
            throw new Exception("invalid / user does not exist");
        }
        return UserObj;
    }
```

Emailcontroller class -

```
@PostMapping("/send-otp")
    public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        
        int otp = random.nextInt(999999);
        
        String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
        String toEmail = email;
        String body = "<h1> OTP = " + otp + "</h1>";
        
          this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
          return ("succes");
    }
```

I just want to call /send-otp in /login if the the login details are correct.

Comment: It's a method in the same controller, right? So just call it as a method. Just keep in mind that the return value of the `sendOtp` is a String. For controllers (annotated with `@Controller` and not `@RestController`), this means it's the name of the view to render. That rendering won't be done unless the `loginUser` method returns the same String, or something else that causes a view to be rendered such as `View` or `ModelAndView`.

Comment: @RobSpoor No both methods are in different controller.

Comment: You can try injecting the second controller in the first one. Not something I've done before. Alternatively, move the `sendOtp` code to a separate service. The new service method can return `void`, as the view to render should be defined by the controller, not the service.

Comment: @RobSpoor injecting controller in another controller is antipattern. The best solution is, as you suggested, move code into separate service and use it in both endpoints.

Comment: @Johnczek I have already made another service for /send-otp. I am new to springboot so can you explain me what do you mean by use it in both endpoint?

Comment: @HarshitToxia If you have, for example, 2 endpoints which first one (endpoint 1) consists of calling methods A and B and second endpoint consists of calling method B, you should have these methods A and B in dedicated service (or 2 services if these methods has nothing in common). And then you just inject that service in both controllers and call these methods from there. Controller SHOULD NOT hold any further logic, thats what services do.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ServiceOTP class like this:

```
public class ServiceOTP {
       public void sendOTP(String email) {
           int otp = random.nextInt(999999);
            
            String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
            String toEmail = email;
            String body = "<h1> OTP = " + otp + "</h1>";
            
              this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
       }
    }
```

Emailcontroller class -

```
@PostMapping("/send-otp")
public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
      myServiceOTPInstance.sendOTP(email);
      return ("succes")
}
```

Controller classs ---

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public SessionHandling loginUser(@RequestBody SessionHandling login) throws Exception {
   //your code
    myServiceOTPInstance.sendOTP(email)
   //your code
}
```